# What is equivalent for SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable() in CSOM

Tags: 2013, csom

In Server Side Object Model (SSOM) to return **listitemcollection** into **datatable**, we can just write [SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx)

What is its equivalent in CSOM?

I found this link which has code to return listitemcollection to datatbale http://sp77.blogspot.in/2015/04/listitemcollection-as-datatable-in.html

But is there similar method available in CSOM as there in SSOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no similar method in **CSOM** (C#). You have to build manually as like your reference.

You can check the methods of `ListItemCollection` from *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitemcollection_methods.aspx)*

Comment: Thanks Atish. I thought there will be something similar available which will help me. I will wait if someone else comes with some other idea, otherwise will accept your answer.

Comment: As Atish said , CSOM does not support GetDataTable() method on ListItemCollection.you have use caml query to get list collection and store the collection value in data row by Iterate through the loop.

Comment: Its not CSOM and won't return a Collection, but a REST call to the /items endpoint of a List will get you all in a JSON structure

Comment: **CSOM (C#)** returns a collection. `public class ListItemCollection : ClientObjectCollection<ListItem>`. Doesn't it?